# Laravel filtering eager loading with take() not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, take

I have below relation definitions:

**Post:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $fillable = ['title','content','category_id','featured_image','slug'];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');    
  }

  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
  }

}
```

**Category:**

```
class Category extends Model
{

  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
  }
}
```

In my controller's index function i am trying to get the **top 3 categories(In terms of number of posts) with their top 3 latest posts**. I did the below which works fine as long as i am not including the inner **take** method:

```
$cats_and_posts = Category::with(['posts'=>function($query){
        $query->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->take(3)->get();
    }])->withCount('posts')->orderBy('posts_count','desc')->take(3)->get();
```

If i include the inner **take** method, some of the categories are loading with empty *posts* relation. here is what dd produces for the "cats_and_posts" variable:

```
 #items: array:3 [▼
0 => Category {#261 ▶}
1 => Category {#260 ▶}
2 => Category {#243 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "posts" => Collection {#269 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
]
}
```

Without the inner take method all the posts for the categories are loading!

Would much appreciate some help. Can not figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put a `->get()` in the subquery for the relation.

```
$cats_and_posts = Category::with([
        'posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->take(3);
        }
    ])
    ->withCount('posts')
    ->orderBy('posts_count', 'desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem! the inner query is only returning empty collection for some of the categories!